# vsc won't recognize sklearn

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn

I have scikit-learn installed and although it works fine in jupyter notebook, vsc keeps bringing up `No module named 'sklearn'`. I have uninstalled and reinstalled it and i have upgraded it, nothing works .

```
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
Successfully installed scikit-learn-1.1.2
PS K:\portfolio_py> & "k:/portfolio_py/temporary app/virtual/Scripts/python.exe" k:/portfolio_py/titanic_random_forest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "k:\portfolio_py\titanic_random_forest.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Ridge
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
PS K:\portfolio_py> pip install scikit-learn --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\users\manos\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\manos\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.0.0 in c:\users\manos\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\users\manos\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.3.2 in c:\users\manos\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.9.0)


PS K:\portfolio_py> & "k:/portfolio_py/temporary app/virtual/Scripts/python.exe" k:/portfolio_py/titanic_random_forest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "k:\portfolio_py\titanic_random_forest.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Ridge
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
PS K:\portfolio_py>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where your `sklearn` package is installed

> ```
> Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\users\manos\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (1.1.2)
> ```

This is your command to run the code

> ```
> PS K:\portfolio_py> & "k:/portfolio_py/temporary app/virtual/Scripts/python.exe" k:/portfolio_py/titanic_random_forest.py
> ```

Obviously, your `sklearn` package is installed in the **python310** environment. And you use the python interpreter in the **virtual** environment to run the code.

So the reason for the error is that the interpreter you are currently using is not the same interpreter that you installed the `sklearn` package with.

##### There are two solutions here

- Switch the currently used interpreter

  1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
  2. Python: Select Interpreter
  3. Select the **python310** interpreter with the `sklearn` package installed
- Install `sklearn` for the current virtual environment

  1. Select the interpreter in the virtual environment
  2. Create a new terminal to activate the virtual environment
  3. Install `sklearn` in the terminal